# How is STL thread-safety going when using "/Zc:threadSafeInit-" in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3?

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2015, static, windows-xp, std

I'm using vc140_xp toolsets for supporting Windows XP. 
Before Vista, there is a known problem which is occured in DLL using implicit TLS. 
And, magic statics implementation of VS2015 uses implicit TLS. 
Therefore, there is a need to turn off magic statics for developing DLL which supports XP. 
For that, "/Zc:threadSafeInit-" is used.

What I'm wondering is that thread-safety of STL when using "/Zc:threadSafeInit-". 
What I thought is that if in STL there is a code which uses static object in a function, the code may be thread-unsafe. 
But, it is just my thought. And I can't find the exact description for that.

How is STL thread-safety going when using /Zc:threadSafeInit- in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3? 
Can originally thread-safe feature of STL be going to be thread-unsafe if using /Zc:threadSafeInit- ? 
If yes, is there no way for supporting XP and keeping thread-safety of STL, both?

Comment: No, that is not something to worry about.  STL containers are not thread-safe in the first place, you won't make that worse with this option.  Google "is std::vector thread safe" to learn more.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, STL containers are not thread-safe. But, containers are not all of STL.. There are thread-safe features in STL like `std::shared_ptr` and `std::iostream`.

Comment: I found the material about it. It says "The STL now avoids using thread-safe “magic statics” except when absolutely necessary, improving codegen." (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/08/12/stl-fixes-in-vs-2015-update-3/)